# Parallel Programming Assignment in java

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am busy on a parallel programming assignment, and I am really stuck. To be honest I am not entirely sure how each method works, but I think I have an idea.

I need to sum an array of consecutive values (in parallel). Seems easy enough, but I get 0 as an answer every time I try. I really don't know why.

```
class SumThreaded extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
    static int SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD = 10000;
    double lo=0.0;
    double hi=0.0;

    long[] arr;

    public SumThreaded(long[] array, double a, double b) {
        arr=array;
        lo=a;
        hi=b;


    }

    public Integer compute() {

        //System.out.println(mid);
        if(hi - lo <= SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD) {
            int ans = 0;
            for(int i= (int) lo; i < hi; ++i)
                ans += arr[i];
            return ans;
        }
        else {
            SumThreaded left = new SumThreaded(arr,lo,(hi+lo)/2.0);
            SumThreaded right = new SumThreaded(arr,(hi+lo)/2.0,hi);
            left.fork();
            int rightAns = right.compute();
            int leftAns = left.join();
            return leftAns+rightAns;

        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){

        int size = 1000000;
        long [] testArray=new long[size]; 

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            testArray[i]=i+1;
        }

        SumThreaded t = new SumThreaded(testArray,0.0,testArray.length); 
        ForkJoinPool fjPool = new ForkJoinPool();
        int result =fjPool.invoke(t);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To start with, properly formatting your code makes it much easier to read and debug.

Comment: This sure seems like a whole lotta code for what should take just a few lines. Try separating out your concerns so that each class does the minimum it can.

Comment: Gah!  What did you do to the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that you have two separate constructors for `SumThreaded`, only one of which sets the class's fields. When you're feeding in the `long[] array` from the `new` in `sumArray`, you throw the array away. You need to pick whether you're using `int`s or `long`s (and the sum of a big array is likely to need a `long`) and then make sure your values are getting set appropriately. Debugging and setting a breakpoint on `compute` would have shown you this.

Comment: I'm very sorry about that, I completely missed that extra contructor ( it's pretty late :P). I edited the OP, but I am getting a ClassCastException.

Comment: *Which* `ClassCastException`? It prints out plenty of detail that usually tells you exactly where and what the problem is.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: `java.lang.Thread cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread
 
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.fork(Unknown Source)
 at SumThreaded.compute(SumThreaded.java:24)
 at Main.sumArray(SumThreaded.java:36)
 at Main.main(SumThreaded.java:49)`code`

I am really not familiar with the fork/join framework :/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903429/java-lang-thread-cannot-be-cast-to-java-util-concurrent-forkjoinworkerthread

Comment: Thanks Theodore, I edited the OP again, but now its a logical error ( the answer is wrong)

Comment: @ShuaibParker Wondered when you'd get to that point. I'll give you a hint: Think about how rounding works with integer math.

Comment: Edited the OP again.Am I missing something? Double division should do the trick?

Comment: @ShuaibParker The index for an array has to be an integer for obvious reasons; changing it to `double` just moves the rounding error around. What happens to your `left` and `right` halves when the array range has an odd number of elements?

Comment: Wooot, thanks man . Changing from Integer to Long did the trick. I had no idea it would make such a massive difference in the answer :/.